# How to safely pass the results from a continuously running child thread back to its parent?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

My Application looks like this:

```
public class Server {
    private InititationServer initServer;
    private ArrayList<Socket> workerSockets;

    public Server() {
        workerSockets = new ArrayList<Socket>();
        initServer = new InitiationServer();
        (new Thread(initServer)).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server();
    }

    //...
}
```

with

```
public class InitiationServer implements Runnable {
    private ServerSocket initSocket;

    //...

    public void run()
        while (true) {
            Socket workerSocket = initSocket.accept();
            // Add workerSocket to Server.workerSockets
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

The InititationServer implements Runnable and ServerSocket.accept()s incoming Sockets in run(). How do i pass these accepted Sockets back to Server.workerSockets in a thread safe manner?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You do not have application. What you have presented is a data structure. At this point it is to vague to answer.

Comment: What are you trying to pass back? result of `InititationServer`?

Comment: What do you mean by continuously running child thread.

Comment: Use LinkedBlockingQueue or other thread safe flavor of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` for `workerSockets` instead of `ArrayList`, because it thread-safe.

Or you can use `workerSockets = Collections.synchronizedList(workerSockets);` your list will be thread-safe, but I recommend you to use first method rather than second.

[CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

[Collections.synchronizedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to CopyOnWriteArrayList. Will try later and post results.

Comment: @HashBanana You are welcome. Maybe you mark my answer as solution? ;)

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm new here. Can't upvote yet and missed the greyed out check. Done now though! :)